# Excel: Sum cells if they share an identical unknown string

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, sum, uniqueidentifier

I have 154,901 rows of data that look like this:

```
Text String | 340
```

Where "Text String" represents a variable string that has no other pattern or order to it and cannot be predicted in any mathematical way, and 340 represents a random integer. How can I find the sum of all of the values sharing an identical string, and organize this data based on total per unique string?

For example, say I have the dataset

```
Alpha | 3
Alpha | 6
Beta  | 4
Gamma | 1
Gamma | 3
Gamma | 8
Omega | 10
```

I'm looking for some way to present the data as:

```
Alpha | 9
Beta  | 4
Gamma | 12
Omega | 10
```

The point of this being that I have a dataset so large that I cannot enumerate this manually, and I have a finite yet unknown amount of strings that I cannot reliably predict what they are.

Comment: Consider using a pivot table, and then aggregate the numbers by string.  This is probably the least ugly option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Consider using a pivot table, and then aggregate the numbers by string. This is probably the least ugly option. – Tim Biegeleisen